# Accessing user control properties of master page inside a content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In a project master pages do not have code behind files; and in content page I need to read user control's properties which is inside master page. Can you please advice how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your content page

```
YourControl YourControlObj = this.Master.FindControl("YourControl") as YourControl;
```

Comment: doest his work? i dont think so..! when u write "YourControl" without any reference it gives error..!

Answer (score 0):

In Master Page -

```
<asp:TextBox Id="txt" />
```

In content page -

```
TextBox t = this.Master.FindControl("txt") as TextBox;
t.Text = "Some Value";
```

Comment: Ritesh it is a user control. please advice

Comment: I don't think there will be any difference with UserControl.
In master page - `<my:UControl Id="uc" />`
In content page - `UControl t = this.Master.FindControl("uc") as UControl; // You can use property now.`
.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
Literal mpLiteral = (Literal) Master.FindControl("masterPageLiteralControlID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

In Master page

```
<uc1:MyWebUserControl ID="myCtl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

In content page (in code behind )

```
MyWebUserControl myWCtl  = this.Master.FindControl("myCtl") as MyWebUserControl;
```

Comment: I have tried with this but it wont work:
In Master page:
<uc1:ShoppingCartControl ID="myCtl" runat="server" />

In Content Page:
ShoppingCartControl myWCtl = this.Master.FindControl("myCtl") as ShoppingCartControl;

It give error : "the type or namespace does not exist! any idea?